# Meteor - How do I save local data persistently on mobile?

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, meteor

Is it possible for data in a Meteor app deployed to a mobile device to be saved locally so that it persists across sessions.

I would like my MEteor app to be used without Internet connection.

However, the local database keeps resetting everytime I start a new session. This is how it behaves in the browser I know but not something I want happening on an app. I assume every time the app is replaced in memory, the local data storage is reset.

I've tried using Session variables, tried saving it in collections and anonymous collections - they all get wiped every time I delete the app from my recent apps list.

For Meteor, is there a way to save data to a mobile persistently?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to start here: https://blog.groupbuddies.com/posts/45-offline-web-apps-with-meteor